# How can I have a custom workflow triggered to start at the completion of an Approval workflow?

Tags: designer-workflow

Using SharePoint 2013, I have a Approval-SharePoint 2010 workflow (called Probe Long Term Hold) start when the item is created. I have a second workflow that is supposed to be triggered when the approval workflow completes. It also starts when the item is created and utilizes:

[image]

The idea being that once Probe Long Term Hold is equal to Approved (16), this workflow will start. However, after approving the Probe Long Term Hold, the email is never sent and the second approval never starts.

If I manually restart the workflow after the Probe Long Term Hold has been approved, it will work. But the Wait does not seem to work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably make it an on change workflow. I would also introduce a flag column into the list. The workflow would then go like this:

```
If probe long term hold equals 16 and flag column equals No
Email.. 
Start approval...
Update Current item set flag equal to Yes
```

Make sense?

Comment: But the IF statement only checks once the workflow has started, right? So this would only check Probe Long Term Hold once at the beginning (which would be equal to 2). I need it to loop checking.

Comment: it would be firing every time the item changes. The only time it would run is when long term hold equals 16 and the flag is no, then itll do the approval and mark the flag as yes and any subsequent edits won't cause the workflow code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, it seems to be that Wait only performs a check when an item is edited. Approval workflow completion does not edit an item; therefore, the check is never performed.

To circumvent this, I negated the original approval workflow and built a custom workflow that included an approval workflow (see the first line of Step 1 below).

[image]

One thing to note, the Approval Status does get updated, but even if the item is Rejected, the next line will still execute. That's why I then have the If statement to check the local variable IsItemApproved that is linked to the previous Approval workflow. I then have the workflow update my own column called Probe Long Term Hold Status.